# Take numbers from string array index, multiply them together?

Tags: java

So in this scenario I have an array with multiple cards within a deck. These cards in each index are ranked S1R1, S1R2, S1R3, S2R1, S2R2, S2R3. I need to be able to extract both numbers from each index position and multiply them together and eventually add them up.

```
For example, 
position 0 would be 1 * 1 = 1
position 1 would be 1 * 2 = 2
position 2 would be 1 * 3 = 3
etc. etc.
```

The code for this example changes based on user input so it's tough to give you the code to work with.

```
public void createDeckofCards() {
    SizeOfDeck = NumberOfRanks * NumberOfSuits;

    Cards newCard = new Cards();

    newCard.setCards ( NumberOfRanks, NumberOfSuits );

    newDeck = new String [ SizeOfDeck ];


    int counter = 0;
    for (int whatSuit = 1; whatSuit <= NumberOfSuits; whatSuit++) {
        for (int rank = 1; rank <= NumberOfRanks; rank++) {
            newDeck[counter++] = newCard.createCard(rank, whatSuit);
        }
    } 
}
```

This is what calls upon method createCard() which creates each card based on how many cards the user inputs. So newDeck[] contains all these cards that I need to break into numbers and summarize eventually. (Making a histogram of 100,000 hands of cards)

Thank you for your time, and I appreciate any input

Comment: I'm a little confused what you are asking. Could you sum up your problem in a single sentence?

Comment: I'm not asking for someone to solve my homework... I am trying to figure out how to extract numbers from an array. I could see it being possible if I find a way to take these numbers and put them into a new array, and then multiply positions 0 & 1, 2 & 3, etc.

Comment: But wouldn't that not be possible because it's currently a string with letters S & R in each index? I figure the index needs to be broken apart first to pick out the numbers individually @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: @Twissted You can use regex ^S([\\d]+)R([\\d]+)$ Please see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50979561/1262248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex

```
^S([\\d]+)R([\\d]+)$
```

Code Snippet:

```
String s ="S3R4";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^S([\\d]+)R([\\d]+)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if(matcher.find()){
System.out.println((Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))*Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2))));
}
```

Output:

```
12
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make your card an object (`Card` perhaps) with properties of suit and rank.
Give it methods to return:

- a symbolic form (`toString` is a logical choice): `return "S" + suit + "R" + rank;`
- a value form (`getValue()`): `return suit * rank;`

With that, you can create an array of `Card` instead of an array of `String`.

If you need the ability to convert the symbolic representations ("S1R7", "S3R9") to the physical object, create a `Map<String, Card>`. You can  populate it with `map.put(card.toString(), card);`.

To look up a card you just need to `Card card = map.get("S1R2");`
Then the value is available as `card.getValue()`

Comment: Interesting, that makes a lot of sense actually. Thank you for your input

Comment: I believe this is the way it is meant to be done but with all the rest of my code being completed as is and I cannot seem to conceptualize creating a Card object for each card made then returning this object to be saved within an array I am most likely going to use the regex. I will continue messing around with this for tn though. Ty again.